# How to select customized TOP10 rows by variable?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the sales and cost data by models. The code below select TOP10 models by sales and all the rest are sum up in new category "Others" which is 11th row.

```
df <- data.frame (model  = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N"),
                 sale = c(100,300,140,456,345,456,456,780,40,560,560,456,350,500),
                 cost = c(1340,330,440,443,365,437,478,700,30,460,160,456,650,100))


#TOP10 by sale
order <- df %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(pos = row_number(desc(sale)),
         model = ifelse(pos>10, 'Others', model),
         pos = ifelse(pos>10, 11, pos)) %>%
  group_by(model, pos) %>%
  summarise(cost= sum(cost), sale= sum(sale), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  arrange(pos)
```

Output:

```
   model    pos  cost  sale
 1 H          1   700   780
 2 J          2   460   560
 3 K          3   160   560
 4 N          4   100   500
 5 D          5   443   456
 6 F          6   437   456
 7 G          7   478   456
 8 L          8   456   456
 9 M          9   650   350
10 E         10   365   345
11 Others    11  2140   580
```

The sale of category A is put in "other" since it has low a sale (100) and is not in TOP10.
Now, I want to include A in this TOP 10 in any case, no matter how much sale it has. So output should be TOP9 + 'A' + 'Others':

Expected output:

```
   model    pos  cost  sale
 1 H          1   700   780
 2 J          2   460   560
 3 K          3   160   560
 4 N          4   100   500
 5 D          5   443   456
 6 F          6   437   456
 7 G          7   478   456
 8 L          8   456   456
 9 M          9   650   350
10 A         10   100   1340
11 Others    11  2140   580
```

(Thus change must be done in the given code)

Answer (score 1):

To be able to automate it, I created a function for you. You can easily specify the parameters and get the output quickly. Also, this function can be modified at a later stage based on your requirements:

```
Top10BySales = function(DataFrame,TopN=10, IncludeModels) {
## Dataframe -> User needs to specify the dataframe 
## TopN -> Do you want to limit the analysis by top 10 or change it? Default value is 10
## IncludeModels -> Here you will specify which models you want to include

## Ranking the models based on sales
  df1 = DataFrame %>%
    arrange(desc(sale)) %>%
    mutate(Ranking = 1:nrow(DataFrame),
           Include = ifelse(Ranking<=TopN, model, "Other")) 

## Grouping the models  
  df2 = df1 %>%
    mutate(Ranking = ifelse(Include!="Other", Ranking, 10+1)) %>%
    group_by(Include,Ranking) %>%
    summarise(cost= sum(cost), sale= sum(sale), .groups = 'drop') 
  
## Checking the length of IncludeModelsVector
  if (length(IncludeModels) == 0) {
    df2=df2
  } else {
    df3 = data.frame(ModelNames = IncludeModels)
    df3$Inclusion = ifelse(df3$ModelNames %in% df1$Include, "Yes", "No")
    df3 = df3 %>% filter(Inclusion=="No")
    df_original = df1 %>% filter(model %in% df3$ModelNames)
    df_original$Num = 1:nrow(df_original)
    for (i in 1:nrow(df_original)) {
      df2[nrow(df2)-df_original[i,]$Num,] = df_original[i,c(1,4,3,2)] ## Replacing the values
    }
  }
  
  return(df2 %>% arrange(Ranking))
  
  }
```

### Using the function

To use this function, please see the picture below:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello! Did my response meet your requirements? Please consider upvoting and selecting the green tick mark on the left if it solved your issue. This will help other members of the community who are struggling with the similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: I liked how you created a function to automate the whole process. Good Job!!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be making use of `bind_rows` after removing the 10th line and adding only where `model` == A:

```
library(tidyverse)
#TOP10 by sale
 df %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(pos = row_number(desc(sale)),
         model = ifelse(pos>10, 'Others', model),
         pos = ifelse(pos>10, 11, pos)) %>%
   group_by(model, pos) %>%
   summarise(cost= sum(cost), sale= sum(sale), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   arrange(pos) %>% 
   slice(-10) %>% 
   bind_rows(df %>% 
               filter(model == "A")) %>% 
   mutate(pos = replace_na(pos, 10)) %>% 
   arrange(pos)
```

```
   model    pos  cost  sale
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 H          1   700   780
 2 J          2   460   560
 3 K          3   160   560
 4 N          4   100   500
 5 D          5   443   456
 6 F          6   437   456
 7 G          7   478   456
 8 L          8   456   456
 9 M          9   650   350
10 A         10  1340   100
11 Others    11  2140   580
```

Comment: if A is already in TOP10, then there is double A in the output. How can we avoid this? For instance if A is equal to 1000. I want to automatize the process

Answer (score 0):

You can mutate in 2 steps, before grouping and manipulate the pos variable to fix the order. This solves the problem in the comments to the other answer.

```
order <- df %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(pos = row_number(desc(sale))) %>% 
  mutate(pos = ifelse(model == "A" & pos > 10, 11, ifelse(pos > 10, 12, pos)),
         model = ifelse(pos>11, 'Others', model)) %>%
  group_by(model, pos) %>%
  summarise(cost= sum(cost), sale= sum(sale), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  arrange(pos)
```